# How can I print contents instead of file name from using linux find command?

Tags: linux, find, cat

I have thousands of unl files named something like this `cbs_cdr_vou_20180624_603_126_239457.unl`. I wanted to print all the lines from those files by using following command. but its giving me only file names. I don't need file names, I just need contents from those files.

```
find -type f -name 'cbs_cdr_vou_20180615*.unl'  > /home/fifa/cbs/test.txt
```

Current Output:

```
./cbs_cdr_vou_20180615_603_129_152023.unl
./cbs_cdr_vou_20180615_603_128_219001.unl
./cbs_cdr_vou_20180615_602_113_215712.unl
./cbs_cdr_vou_20180615_602_120_160466.unl
./cbs_cdr_vou_20180615_603_125_174428.unl
./cbs_cdr_vou_20180615_601_101_152369.unl
./cbs_cdr_vou_20180615_603_133_193306.unl
```

Expected output:

```
8801865252020|200200|20180613100325|;
8801837463298|200200|20180613111209|;
8801845136955|200200|20180613133708|;
8801845205889|200200|20180613141140|;
8801837612072|200200|20180613141525|;
8801877103875|200200|20180613183008|;
8801877167964|200200|20180613191607|;
8801845437651|200200|20180613200415|;
8801845437651|200200|20180613221625|;
8801839460670|200200|20180613235936|;
```

Please note that, for cat command I'm getting error like `-bash: /bin/logger: Argument list too long` that's why wanted to use `find` instead of `cat` command.

Comment: You still need to use `cat`.

Comment: Yes! Can you please tell me how can I do that? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `find` utility deals with pathnames. If no specific action is mentioned in the `find` command for the found pathnames, the default action is to output them.

You may perform an action on the found pathnames, such as running `cat`, by adding `-exec` to the `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name 'cbs_cdr_vou_20180615*.unl' -exec cat {} + >/home/fifa/cbs/test.txt
```

This would find all regular files in or under the current directory, whose names match the given pattern.  For as large batches of these as possible, `cat` would be called to concatenate the contents of the files.

The output would go to `/home/fifa/cbs/test.txt`.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: Working as expected and execution time is very fast which is really great. Many thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The output of `find` will result with the relevant file names.
You can pipe (`|`) the output to `xargs cat` which will perform the `cat` command on each file.

e.g.:

```
find -type f -name 'cbs_cdr_vou_20180615*.unl' | xargs cat  > /home/fifa/cbs/test.txt
```

Another option will be to use `-exec cat`

```
find -type f -name 'cbs_cdr_vou_20180615*.unl'  -exec cat {} \;  > /home/fifa/cbs/test.txt
```

Comment: Both of your commands are working fine. But a bit slower than **Kusalananda's** command. I guess, execution time is varying on `-exec cat {} \;` and `-exec -cat {} +`.  By the way, Thanks a lot Yaron.

Comment: xargs is vulnerable to spaces in found pathnames; -exec cat {} is not

Comment: `find -print0 | xargs -0` is not vulnerable to spaces/quotes/etc.

Comment: @Rezuan: `-exec cat {} \;` runs cat separately for each file instead of batching them together like xargs.  Don't use it unless you explicitly want that (e.g. a command that only works for one file at a time), or if you need portability to a system without `-exec ... +` and without `-print0` / `xargs -0`.  I'm a bit surprised that `find|xargs` is measurably slower than `-exec cat {} +`, though.  Do you have very few total files, so startup overhead is a lot of the cost?  Or did you only time the `xargs` version while your disk cache was cold?

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the explanation. It was for the disk cache, I realized later on.